# Use Tensorflow trained models as a service

Tags: google-app-engine, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I just started with tensorflow. I was able to successfully train it for a data set that I created. Now the question is that how will I be able to use this model to make predictions. I want to make it as a REST service, to which I will be able to pass some values and get the predictions as response. Any helpful links are also welcome. The model is currently on a VM.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Cloud ML on GCP? It might be exactly what you're looking for.
https://cloud.google.com/ml/

You might need to make a few tweaks to the architecture of your model - like variable batch sizes and adding inputs/outputs to collections - but they are well explained in the [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/)

If performance, scalability and a short downtime if you decide to update the model are not an issue, you could also consider just having a simple flask server with tensorflow installed on it.

If you don't want to use Cloud ML and need to serve a large amount of requests then look into the [tensorflow serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all: try saving and loading your model: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variables/index.html

Then, after training, you can simply call:

`rest_prediction = sess.run(prediction_tensor, feed_dict={x_tensor: user_input})`

An important difference is that during training you have batch_size inputs, but when you have a REST server you have 1 input. The shape (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/resources/dims_types.html) of your tensors should be variable. How you can achieve this can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/resources/faq.html#tensor-shapes

If you post a short and simple code snippet we might be able to help you better.

Comment: This helps.. but i ended up using a method where I hit the .pb files generated by my code..